# Cloud Foundry Django exit_status=-1

Tags: django, cloud-foundry

Im trying to deploy an app using cloud foundry an im getting this error and the app is crashing. i've tried to change the buildpack but nothing happens.

I don't know how to get more errors.

cf logs returns this log

```
     OUT Submodule 'compile-extensions' (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/compile-extensions.git) registered for path 'compile-extensions'
2017-02-25T11:08:59.56-0300 [STG/0]      ERR Cloning into 'compile-extensions'...
2017-02-25T11:09:00.23-0300 [STG/0]      OUT Submodule path 'compile-extensions': checked out 'a76a1ecab87f514248222e50fdc9f46c37078109'
2017-02-25T11:09:00.39-0300 [STG/0]      OUT -------> Buildpack version 1.5.15
2017-02-25T11:09:13.34-0300 [STG/0]      OUT      $ pip install -r requirements.txt
2017-02-25T11:09:48.99-0300 [STG/16]     OUT -----> Uploading droplet (159M)
2017-02-25T11:10:16.77-0300 [DEA/16]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid a627703f-3fc8-48a2-869c-572b2abec573
2017-02-25T11:10:26.87-0300 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid a627703f-3fc8-48a2-869c-572b2abec573 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"a627703f-3fc8-48a2-869c-572b2abec573", "version"=>"3ead9c26-4535-4dbd-b3ce-d21483bae661", "instance"=>"cb6eda1feaf647aead2e9ef6c2d435b6", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>-1, "exit_description"=>"failed to start", "crash_timestamp"=>1488031826}
```

my manifest.yml is this

```
---
applications:
- name: cs
  instances: 1
  command: bash run.sh
  memory: 200M
  disk_quota: 256M
  random-route: false 
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack.git
```

my Procfile has this line

```
web: python cs/manage.py migrate && python cs/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload
```

and the run.sh has

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$VCAP_APP_PORT" ];
then SERVER_PORT=5000;
else SERVER_PORT="$VCAP_APP_PORT";
fi

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

echo [$0] Starting Django Server...
python cs/manage.py runserver --noreload 0.0.0.0:$SERVER_PORT
```

The same app it's deployed on heroku without any problem so i cannot understand the difference between heroku on cf.

Comment: a.) Your Procfile isn't doing anything.  Setting `command` in your manifest.yml will override what's in Procfile.  For clarity, you should pick one or the other.  b.) Staging appears to be fine.  `pip` isn't installing anything, but it's all running without error.  c.) Your app is failing to start.  It's exiting with exit code -1.  Sorry but can't tell you more than that.  Add some echo statements to your `run.sh` script and bump up the log level in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable debug with "export CF_TRACE=true" and explore your droplet with cf download plugin - more on http://blog.ibmjstart.net/2015/05/22/cf-download/